# ajaxを使って書いたリンクがおささりません

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ajaxを使って書いたいいね（likeと定義）リンクがおささりません。リンクは画面上に表示されているのですが。
コードに問題があるのでしょうか？それともPCに必要なアプリケーションが導入されていないのでしょうか？
コードは、
likes_controller.rbが

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!

  def like
    @note = Note.find(params[:note_id])
    like = current_user.likes.build(note_id: @note.id)
    like.save   
  end

  def unlike
    @note = Note.find(params[:id])
    like = current_user.likes.find_by(note_id: @note.id)
    like.destroy
  end
end
```

_like_links.html.erbが

```
<% if current_user.likes.find_by(note_id: @note.id) %>
  <%= link_to 'いいね！を取り消す', unlike_path(@note.id), method: :delete, remote: true %>
  <% else %>
  <%= link_to 'いいね！', like_path(@note.id), method: :post, remote: true %>
  <% end %>
```

like.js.erbが

```
$('#like-link').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("likes/like_links", note: @note)) %>');
$('#like-count').html('<%= @note.likes.count %>');
```

unlike.js.erbが

```
$('#like-link').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("likes/like_links", note: @note)) %>');
$('#like-count').html('<%= @note.likes.count %>');
```

usersフォルダのshow.html.erが

```
<p id="notice" class="alert-success"><%= notice %></p>

<aside class="sidebar">
 <section>
    <span class="label">プロフィール画像</span>
    <h3 class="user-info">
      <%= image_for(@user) %>
    </h3>
  </section>

 <section>
  <span class="label">Name:</span>
  <h3 class="user-info"><%= @user.name %></h3>
 </section>

 <section>
  <span class="label">Email:</span>
  <h3 class="user-info"><%= @user.email %></h3>
 </section>

 <%= link_to @user.likes.count, like_notes_user_path(@user.id) %>個の投稿にいいね！しています


<% if current_user?(@user) %>
 <section>
    <small><%= link_to　"プロフィールを編集",edit_user_path(@user) %></small>
 </section>
 <% end %>

</aside>

<ul class="notes">
     <h2><%= @title %></h2>
     <%= render @notes %>
</ul>
```

notesフォルダのshow.html.erが

```
<p id="notice" class="alert alert-success">
  <%= notice %>
</p>

<h2>今何してる？</h2>
<p><%= @note.content %></p>

<div id="like-link">
  <!-- 送信先とmethodを指定してください -->
  <%= render "likes/like_links", note: @note %>
</div>

<div>
  <small>
    <%= link_to @note.likes.count, liking_users_note_path(@note.id), id: "like-count" %>人がいいね！といっています
  </small>
</div>

<% if current_user?(@note.user) %>
<%= link_to "つぶやく", edit_note_path(@note.id),class:"edit" %>
<%= link_to "削除", destroy_note_path(@note.id), method: "delete", class: "destroy", "data-confirm" => "本当に削除しますか？" %>
<% end %>
```

liking_users.html.erbが

```
<ul class='show-note'>
  <%= render @note %>
</ul>

<h2 class="heading">いいねしているユーザー一覧 </h2>
<ul class='user-list'>
  <!-- ここでパーシャルファイルを呼び出してください -->
  <%= render @users %>   
</ul>
```

です。

追加です。
いいね！ボタンが正常におささると、
「いいね！
　0人がいいね！といっています」（いいね！と０人の所は押すことができます）
と表示されているところが、
「いいね！を取り消す
　1人がいいね！といっています」（いいね！を取り消すと１人の所は押すことができます）
と変化します。

routes.rbには

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update,:like] do
    member do
      get :like_notes
    end
  end　　　←ここ

  resources :notes, only: [:show, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
    member do
      get :liking_users
    end
  end　　　　←ここ


  get'/top' => 'home#top'

  get'/connection' => 'home#connection'
  get'/notes/new' => 'notes#new'
  post'/notes' =>'notes#create'
  get'/notes' =>'notes#index'
  get'/show/:id' => 'notes#show'
  patch'/notes/:id' =>"notes#update",as:'update_note'
  delete'/notes/:id' =>"notes#destroy",as:'destroy_note'


  post '/like/notes/:id' => 'likes#like', as: 'like'
  delete '/unlike/notes/:id' => 'likes#unlike', as: 'unlike'

  root 'home#top'
  get'/about' => 'home#about'
end
```

で←ここでしめした所が該当するルーターです。
お願いいたします。

Comment: コードの部分は、選択し{} ボタンを押すとうまく投稿できます。http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/ を参考にして下さい。

Comment: @mjy さん、編集していただいてかなり見やすくはなったのですが、別ファイルと思われる内容がいくつかくっついてしまってますね。

Comment: @LePered'OO  さんありがとうございます。直しました。

Comment: @Yuri さん、コードが見やすくなったのでじっくりと見直してみたのですが、Ajax処理として肝心なlike.js.erbとunlike.js.erbに記載されたJavaScriptがいつどのようにして実行されるのかがよくわかりません。notes/show.html.er用のlayoutファイルに何か記述があるのでしょうか。関係ありそうな部分をご質問に追記してください。また「おささりません」は、このご質問では「クリックしても期待した通りの動作にならない」と解釈していいのでしょうか？だとしたら、期待した動作は何なのか、実際にはどんな動作になるのかをご質問に記載してください。

Comment: 「Ajax処理として」〜「追記してください。」の部分はRailsでよくあるAjaxのパターンを私が知らなかっただけ(1年半もRailsの仕事をしていたんですが)のようなので一旦読み飛ばしてください。

Comment: 今の所一番可能性が高いのはルーティングのミスであるように思われます。`likes#like`, `likes#unlike`に飛ばすためのroutes.rbの設定は現在どのようになっていますか?(このスレとは直接関係ないですが、過去のご質問に対する回答の中であなたの問題の解決につながったものには解決のマーキング(スタックオーバーフロー用語では「承認」)をしておいて下さい。)「実際にはどんな動作になるのか」もお忘れなく。

Comment: みなさん、いろいろとコメントをありがとうございます。コードを追加したので、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

とりあえずこの部分に不整合がありますね。
likes_controller.rb:

```
    @note = Note.find(params[:note_id])
```

・`:note_id`でパラメータを取得している。

routes.rb:

```
  post '/like/notes/:id' => 'likes#like', as: 'like'
```

・`:id`としてパラメータを定義している。

この両者は一致させておかないと正しくパラメータが取得できていないはずです。`unlike`側ではroutes.rbでもlikes_controller.rbでも`:id`で参照していますが、`like`側も`params[:id]`として参照すべきでしょう。

かなりややこしい処理なので、他にも何かあるかもしれません。この修正を施してもまだダメな時は、(その時のコードで)一体どんな動作になっているか(ログが取れるならログも含めて)できるだけ詳しい情報をお知らせください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！直りました！！